# Overlay texture using GLES20 and apply rotation

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am working on a project in which I am using `GLES20` to render a texture. I used `GLUtils.texImage2D()` to draw 2d texture image from the `bitmap`.

What do I need to implement to make these changes:

1. Place the texture to the right corner of the screen instead of stretching it to the full screen.
2. Provide incremental rotation frame by frame to the texture.

**Shaders**

```
private final static String FRAGMENT_SHADER =
            "precision mediump float;\n" +
                    "varying vec2 vTextureCoord;\n" +
                    "uniform lowp sampler2D sTexture;\n" +
                    "uniform lowp sampler2D oTexture;\n" +
                    "void main() {\n" +
                    "   lowp vec4 textureColor = texture2D(sTexture, vTextureCoord);\n" +
                    "   lowp vec4 textureColor2 = texture2D(oTexture, vTextureCoord);\n" +
                    "   \n" +
                    "   gl_FragColor = mix(textureColor, textureColor2, textureColor2.a);\n" +
                    "}\n";

 protected static final String DEFAULT_VERTEX_SHADER =
            "attribute highp vec4 aPosition;\n" +
                    "attribute highp vec4 aTextureCoord;\n" +
                    "varying highp vec2 vTextureCoord;\n" +
                    "void main() {\n" +
                    "gl_Position = aPosition;\n" +
                    "vTextureCoord = aTextureCoord.xy;\n" +
                    "}\n";
```

**Texture Generation**

```
int[] textures = new int[1];

@Override
public void setup() {
    super.setup();// 1
    GLES20.glGenTextures(1, textures, 0);
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);
    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
}

@Override
public void onDraw() {
    if (bitmap == null) {
        return;
    }
    int offsetDepthMapTextureUniform = getHandle("oTexture");
    GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE3);
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);
    if (bitmap != null && !bitmap.isRecycled()) {
        GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GLES20.GL_RGBA, bitmap, 0);
    }
    GLES20.glUniform1i(offsetDepthMapTextureUniform, 3);
    // Recycle the bitmap, since its data has been loaded into OpenGL.
    releaseBitmap();
}
```

---

**UPDATED**

I added the `mMVPMatrix` for the texture transformation as suggested by alexrnov. **Both, camera feed and overlay texture are rotating now**.

```
protected static final String VERTEX_SHADER ="attribute highp vec4 aPosition;\n" +
            "uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;\n" +
            "attribute highp vec4 aTextureCoord;\n" +
            "varying highp vec2 vTextureCoord;\n" +
            "void main() {\n" +
            "gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * aPosition;\n" +
            "vTextureCoord = aTextureCoord.xy;\n" +
            "}\n";

@Override
public void onDraw() {
    ....
    Matrix.setIdentityM(mvpMatrix, 0);
    Matrix.rotateM(mvpMatrix, 0, rotation, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    rotation++;
    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, getMVPMatrixAsFloatBuffer(mvpMatrix));
    ...
}
```

[image: Screen Shot]

The project structure is quite complicated. I can't write all the code here. Please refer the [Github Project](https://github.com/rajatsangrame/CameraRecorder)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there is another way, but you can overlay the texture on the rectangle, and apply transformations (movement/rotate) to this rectangle:

Vertex shader:

```
#version 100
uniform mat4 u_mvpMatrix; // MVP-matrix for moving and rotating texture

attribute vec4 a_position; // data of vertices rectangle 
attribute vec2 a_textureCoordinates; 

varying vec2 v_textureCoordinates; 

void main() {
    v_textureCoordinates = a_textureCoordinates;
    gl_Position = u_mvpMatrix * a_position;
}
```

Fragment shader:

```
#version 100
varying vec2 v_textureCoordinates;
uniform sampler2D s_texture;

void main() {
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(s_texture, v_textureCoordinates);
}
```

Approximate Java-code:

```
private final int textureID;
...
textureID = loadTexture(R.raw.texture);
...
@Override
public void draw() {
    GLES20.glUseProgram(programObject);
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(positionLink); 
    GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO[0]);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(positionLink, VERTEX_COMPONENT, 
        GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, VERTEX_STRIDE, 0);
    GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(textureCoordinatesLink);
    GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO[1]);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(textureCoordinatesLink, TEXTURE_COMPONENT, 
        GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, TEXTURE_STRIDE, 0);
    GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID);
    GLES20.glUniform1i(samplerLink, 0);

    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mvpMatrixLink, 1, false,
        RectangleObject3D.getMVPMatrixAsFloatBuffer());

    GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO[2]);
    GLES20.glDrawElements(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, NUMBER_INDICES, 
        GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
    GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(positionLink); 
    GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(textureCoordinatesLink); 
}
```

MVP-matrix:

```
import android.opengl.Matrix

protected val viewMatrix = FloatArray(16)
protected val projectionMatrix = FloatArray(16)
protected val modelMatrix = FloatArray(16)
protected val modelViewMatrix = FloatArray(16)
protected val mvpMatrix = FloatArray(16)
...
Matrix.setLookAtM(viewMatrix, 0, 0f, 0f, 0f,
        0f, 0f, -4f, 0f, 1.0f, 0.0f) // camera
...
// parameters different for portrait and landscape orientation screen android
Matrix.frustumM(projectionMatrix, 0, left, right, bottom, top, near, far)
...
fun spotPosition() { // invoke on every frame
    Matrix.setIdentityM(modelMatrix, 0)
    Matrix.translateM(modelMatrix, 0, x, y, z) // move object
    Matrix.rotateM(modelMatrix, 0, angleX, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f) // rotate object
    Matrix.scaleM(modelMatrix, 0, 4f, 4f, 4f) // scale object 
    Matrix.multiplyMM(modelViewMatrix, 0, viewMatrix, 0, modelMatrix, 0)
    Matrix.multiplyMM(mvpMatrix, 0, projectionMatrix, 0, modelViewMatrix, 0)
}
fun getMVPMatrixAsFloatBuffer(): FloatBuffer = floatBuffer(mvpMatrix)
```

get FloatBuffer (essential in Java SDK):

```
public static FloatBuffer floatBuffer(float[] data) {
    ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(data.length * 4)
                        .order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    FloatBuffer returnBuffer = byteBuffer.asFloatBuffer();
    returnBuffer.put(data).position(0);
    return returnBuffer;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Can you please share something related to the transformation matrix as well. What I understand is, I will need to pass new matrix values to `GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv()` to get rotated texture.

Comment: @XTremePlayer Hello. Added the basis for matrix transformations in answer. You can also see https://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl/motion

Comment: It didn't work for me. Can you please check this by your side. Its too much of code I can't put it in the question. https://pastebin.com/raw/4W6GA2GK   https://pastebin.com/raw/jZwFKVCP

Comment: XTremePlayer It’s hard to understand right away. Here's another example:  https://github.com/skyfe79/LearningOpenGLES2-Android/tree/master/08-1.AmbientLight View a rotating cube with an overlay texture: https://github.com/skyfe79/LearningOpenGLES2-Android/blob/master/08-1.AmbientLight/result.gif

Comment: Thanks for the help. Combining the `projectionMatrix` and `viewMatrix` matrices will also fix the stretching issue of the overlay texture, right ? https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl#coordinate-mapping

Comment: XTremePlayer Yes. You can use this matrix multiplication order. There rotateMatrix is equivalent to the modelMatrix. ModelVievMatrix may be needed to calculate lighting.

Comment: Both, camera feed and overaly texture is rotated as I applied `Matrix.rotateM(mvpMatrix, 0, rotation, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);`  `GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, getMVPMatrixAsFloatBuffer(mvpMatrix));`  XD